# Accessing wordpress database in themes includes folder

Tags: php, wordpress, function, templates, include

So I have a plugin that needs to read off a JSON file that I have included in my template. I have all of my queries set up on a custom template that pulls in the correct data so I know the problem isn't my queries. Is there a way to include the functions.php(or wherever the open database function is) from the wp-includes that will open up the database in a seperate, non-wordpress related page? Please let me know if my wording is confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hacky way is to include the `wp-blog-header.php` file from the root folder.  This loads the WordPress core, and all your plugins and functions will be accessible.

If your WordPress files are at the server root, you could use this:

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Then your WordPress functions should work (`get_posts()`, for example).

Comment: Thank you so much! I wish I would've asked this question a lot earlier than I did. This worked perfectly